# Grabbing image of UIScrollView content - anti-aliasing problem

Tags: iphone, image, uiscrollview

I need to grab the scaled image of content currently visible in UIScrollView. I'm able to get the image but there is discrepancy between anti-aliasing algorithm used by scroll view and the grabbing process. Please look at the image to get my point:

(**left**: as seen in UIScrollView, **right**: as grabbed with renderInContext)

[the image](http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5058/5431202924_3e61335f49.jpg)

I already tried to set interpolation quality, edge antialiasing mask and allow/force anti-alias in context using CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing and CGContextSetShouldAntialias without success. The image is saved to file as an PNG with UIImagePNGRepresentation.

Any ideas how to grab the exact copy of what is visible in scroll view?